# Suppose $p$ is a prime. Show that every element of $GL_2(F_p)$ has order dividing either $p^2 — 1$ or $p(p — 1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Suppose $p$ is a prime. Show that every element of $GL_2(F_p)$ has order dividing either $p^2 — 1$ or $p(p — 1)$.

My thoughts - Can assume that an element of $GL_2(F_p)$ has one of the canonical forms:

- Different roots so two jordan blocks.
- Repeated Root with either one or two jordan blocks.

Where can I go from there? Not sure what I can say about the order of the matrices.

Comment: Fermat's little theorem should help in the case where the matrix is diagonalizable. Try figuring out how to express a general power of the JCF in the other case.

Comment: $p(p-1)$ looks like the order of $\scriptstyle a\begin{pmatrix} 1 & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $p^2-1$ as the order of $\scriptstyle \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -bc & a \end{pmatrix} = a+b \sqrt{c}$

Comment: It cannot be a coincidence that the order of the group is $(p^2-1)(p^2-p)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the characteristic polynomial has roots in $F_p$, then you are in one of the situations described.

If $J =\begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\
0 & b \end{bmatrix}$ then $J^{p-1}=\begin{bmatrix} a^{p-1} & 0 \\
0 & b^{p-1} \end{bmatrix}=I_2$.

If $J=\begin{bmatrix} a & 1 \\
0 & a \end{bmatrix}$ prove that $J^p$ is diagonal, and hence $J^{p(p-1)}=I_2$.

The other situation is if the characteristic polynomial doesn't have roots in $F_p$. Since the characteristic polynomial is quadratic, there exists an extension $F_p \hookrightarrow K$ of degree 2 where the characteristic polynomial has a root, and hence two roots.

Show that the two roots are different (hint: derivative) and hence, in this algebraic extension the Jordan form is
$$$J =\begin{bmatrix} \alpha & 0 \\
0 & \beta \end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow \\J^{p^2-1}=\begin{bmatrix} \alpha^{p^2-1} & 0 \\
0 & \beta^{p^2-1} \end{bmatrix}=I_2 \,.$$

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks.

Comment: @tastykakes When you prove that the roots in the extension are distinct, pay extra attention to the case $p=2$ ;) 2 is often really annoying.

Comment: If the roots are not in $F_p$ then $F_p[J] = F_{p^2}$. I wonder about the case $GL_n$

Comment: @reuns The $GL_n$ case is trickier. For once, the splitting field of the characteristic polynomial can have degree up to $n!$, where $\deg(P)=n$. Also, the situation is complicated more by the fact that the characteristic polynomial could have roots of higher multiplicity in the splitting field.